# Using a computer mic with lm386

Tags: audio, lm386

I'm working on a two way amplifier/intercom for my parents to use in the car because of road noise and hearing problems.

I got a couple LM386n-4 and I've tried the circuit layout from here:
http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Microphone-amplifier-circuit.php

[image]

I've also tried the really stripped down version from this answer:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/473553/76121
[image]

For a microphone I want to use a [computer headset with ear cup for the speaker, and a boom mic for the microphone](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/insignia-on-ear-analog-mono-headset-black/5648055.p?skuId=5648055). It has a 4 section jack for left, right, mic, ground, and the plug also has 4 pins.

Unfortunately I can't get it to work. With one plug I get a weird tone, and when I tried a different one I only got silence.

I'm trying to get some electret mics, but I don't think I will be able to get them delivered in time for Christmas. So, is there a reason that the ones I have won't just work?

[image]

Comment: An electret microphone does need a pull-up resistor to operate and give an output signal. Judging from the photo of your setup, if the red cable is coming from the mic then it's quite normal you're not hearing anything because there's no pull-up resistor there.. If you don't know the pinout or you are not sure if it's coming from the mic, then you can test the cables with a multimeter by measuring in resistance mode. Low resistances (e.g. 4, 8, 16, or 32 Ohms) indicate that there's a speaker there. Common is always ground.

Comment: Stick with your first circuit because it biases the microphone properly. However, it can easily turn into an oscillator due to how you might wire the circuit on breadboard.

Comment: It's typically illegal for the driver to wear headphone; there might (?) be an exception for a single ear, but consider if this is wise.

Comment: @RohatKılıç The white one is the microphone, Thankfully the headphone jacks are labeled: ( https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B089222S84 ). For the pull up resistor I have a 10k right now because the the diagram didn't specify what value to use (R1, variable), there is no information on the one in the headset and what it needs, and something I found said that 10k is ok. But if you know the right way to calculate it I would appreciate the info!

Comment: @Andyaka if it wasn't on the breadboard, would it be less chance of being an oscillator? I'm wondering if that's why I get the weird tone. I just didn't want to make it permanent if I didn't know I had the wires in the right places.

Comment: You apply power to the LM386 first, then tee-off power to the microphone and possibly add another RC filter for extra power line filtering @AndyD273

Comment: @ChrisStratton These are in fact single cup headphones, which I believe are legal in my area since they don't block road noise. But that's why I want to use the headphone jack, so I can change up what's plugged in just in case.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Hey, thanks for the tip on resistance. Apparently the audio jacks that I got are mislabeled. I tested the resistance of the plug directly (once I looked up which ring is the ground), then plugged it into the jack and tested all the combinations until I figured out which was a speaker and which was the mic. Now it is working. The signal is pretty noisy on the breadboard, but I'm kind of hoping that it's just because it's on the breadboard? Otherwise I'll have to figure out how to add a filter to it.

Comment: @AndyD273 That's good news. As for the noise issue, yeah, hooking up a circuit on a breadboard when even millivolts are important is a terrible idea. Plus, 10k as a bias resistor for electret mic may be a bit high as it can lead to higher offset voltage and thus early clipping. Most electret mics are happy with 2k2 to 4k7 for Vcc = 5V. Maybe you can try decreasing the 10k to something around 2k2 or 3k3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the big problem was that the microphone jacks I bought were mislabeled as to which connector went to which ring on the plug.

Big thanks to the commenters that helped point me in the right direction!